# deleted columns created again and again while project deployed in Tomcat?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I created a table with 10 columns using HIbernate tags and Model(POJO class). After , I removed 4 unwanted columns from POJO Model and re-deploy my project, Again those deleted columns also generated? How to i removed those unwanted columns from tomcat cache and completely avoid to created those

Comment: how do you create the tables?

Comment: using Hibernate  annotations in Java Spring  Model class

Comment: and when you redeploy you are sure that the old app does no longer exsits

Comment: yes, I dropped my table from DB, clean my project , re-build using maven, re-published into tomcat-8.5 and redeploy. Again the same table with 10 columns created.  And, I manually delete the wtsweb-apps and work folders and re deployed into tomcat. I am using Spring tool suite

Comment: and you are really sure that hibernate is creating the table from your entity?

Comment: yes Sir, I created many tables from hibernate only

Comment: Can show some code? Your mapping XML config if available etc